# Rack or Rails Issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, encoding, rack

I'm not sure what has happened. My app was running fine, and now every so often it fails with this error. I'm using Capistrano and Unicorn.

The problem is fixed every time by just running `cap deploy` again, but then it breaks shortly after.

```
Started POST "/monitorings" for 21.987.109.224 at 2012-06-20 08:05:49 +0100
Processing by MonitoringsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"#", "monitoring"=>{"inspection_type"=>"Intensive", "is_revoked"=>"0", "note_attributes"=>{"content"=>"", "attention_required"=>"0", "resolved"=>"0"}, "scenario_ids"=>[""], "outlet_id"=>"560"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
Expire fragment (?-mix:daily) (7.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms

ArgumentError (invalid %-encoding (0607214051%2Fregions%2F11-20120607201444%2Fregions%2F38-20120618184202%2Fregions%2F3-20120409175338%2Fregions%2F36-20120618184137%2Fregions%2F12-20120607202042%2Fregions%2F13-20120607202050%2Fregions%2F37-20120618184150%2Fregions%/2F14-20120607202100%2Fregions%2F6-20120607201339%2Fregions%2F15-20120607202119%2Fregions%2F1-20120409175338%2Fregions%2F16-20120607202129%2Fregions%2F39-20120618184218%2Fregions%2F17-20120607202139%2Fregions%2F40-20120618184229%2F/regions%2F4-20120603182949%2Fregions%2F18-20120607202152%2Fregions%2F19-20120607202200%2Fregions%2F20-20120607202209%2Fregions%2F21-20120607202215%2Fregions%2F22-20120607202223%2Fregions%2F23-20120607202229%2Fregions%2F24-20120607/202236%2Fregions%2F41-20120618184240%2Fregions%2F25-20120607202245%2Fregions%2F26-20120607202253%2Fregions%2F42-20120618184248%2Fregions%2F43-20120618184256%2Fregions%2F27-20120607202301%2Fregions%2F28-20120607213722%2Fregions%2F2/9-20120607202317%2Fregions%2F30-20120607202324%2Fregions%2F44-20120618184306%2Fregions%2F31-20120607202332%2Fregions%2F45-20120618184313%2Fregions%2F32-20120607202339%2Fregions%2F34-20120607202355)):
  app/sweepers/outlet_sweeper.rb:13:in `expire_cache'
  app/sweepers/outlet_sweeper.rb:5:in `after_update'
  app/controllers/monitorings_controller.rb:114:in `after_create'
  app/controllers/monitorings_controller.rb:54:in `create'
  config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:6:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
```

The app is hosted on a VPS running Ubuntu 10.04 which as far as I can tell is completely up to date (I ran `apt-get upgrade && apt-get install`).

Just in case anyone's wondering, the sweeper is:

```
class OutletSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Outlet

  def after_update(outlet)
    expire_cache
  end

  # expire_fragment calls moved to their own method
  def expire_cache

    @controller ||= ActionController::Base.new

    expire_fragment(%r{daily})
    puts "Expired Daily Cache"

    expire_fragment(%r{weekly})
    puts "Expired Weekly Cache"
  end

  # Allows us to call the expire_cache method from rake
  def self.rake_sweep
    puts "Begining Expire Cache"
    new.expire_cache
  end

end
```

Comment: which cache store are you using? file? memcached? memory? do you have a complete backtrace (including rails stack)?

Comment: I'm pretty new to caching, and have gone with the default (which ever that is). In the view I'm using (- cache "weekly" do) etc.
The above is all the information I have on the error. Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by changing the following in the sweeper:

```
expire_fragment(%r{daily})
puts "Expired Daily Cache"

expire_fragment(%r{weekly})
puts "Expired Weekly Cache"
```

to:

```
expire_fragment "daily"
puts "Expired Daily Cache"

expire_fragment "weekly"
puts "Expired Weekly Cache"
```